# What type of refrigerant do I need for an 07 Honda Civic Hybrid......?

Tags: honda, ac, civic, compressor

My 07 civic AC stopped working and clutch no longer engages. I checked fuses, relays, etc..and all were fine. I did not realize Hybrids use a different type of compressors (use air conditioning compressors that are operated by an electric motor instead of a drive belt.) Now mine does a drive belt attached to the AC compressor.

Looking through some forums I found that some refrigerants have PAG oil that are not compatible with hybrids.

Any recommendation on what type of refrigerant (brand, type, etc..) I should be using?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not positive, but you most likely need R134a, which is the refrigerant of the day for 2007. Just get one without PAG oil in it. If you haven't had an oil leak or changed your compressor, you shouldn't have to worry about adding oil anyway. Leaving as a comment because I'm not positive.

Comment: I forgot to mention this but, last year I did put R134A refrigerant from Walmart and not sure if it has PAG oil. If I needed oil, how would I go about this process? Removing compressor..?

Comment: If you don't have an understanding about how much oil, you're better off taking it to an AC shop. Realistically, just as I stated, if you  haven't lost any PAG oil, you don't need any more. To my understanding it doesn't evaporate. If it hasn't leaked or you haven't changed out the compressor, you won't need any. Any refrigerant you buy will tell you if it has oil in it or not. Get plain Jane R134a and you should be golden.

Comment: I've worked on AC systems. just never hybrids